# how can i make error toast message if data is not inserted into firebase (this is my code)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my code qr code scanner

```
databaseReference.child(id).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            onBackPressed();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

the successful task is working

Comment: The is an `if` there, what about and `else`?

Comment: i tried putting else but its not working

Comment: Please show what you tried with the `else` that cutiko suggested, and *how* you tested it.

Comment: can i comment the code or ill just edit it? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @hsai Simply edit your question. There is an edit button under it. Please also respond with @.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see you are using wrong onBackPressed();

```
databaseReference.child(id).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Error handling here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA INSERT ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        onBackPressed(); //This will exit the screen, you should consider whether to use it
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**:
I have updated the code, the best way to display toast for both Fragment and Activity. And I have added **Log.d** to check where the program runs and if it's working properly

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int MSG_SHOW_TOAST = 1;

    void displayMessage(String message, boolean isLengthLong) {
        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int longShow = isLengthLong ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), message, longShow).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Demo extends BaseFragment {
    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        displayMessage("Ahihi", false);
    }

    public void yourMethod() {
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // Put the log here, Check the log outputted from mobile on android studio to make sure this is working
                Log.d(TAG, "yourMethod: onComplete: status task is " + task.isSuccessful());
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    displayMessage("DATA INSERTED", true);
                } else {
                    // Put the log here, Check the log outputted from mobile on android studio to make sure this is working
                    Log.d(TAG, "yourMethod: onComplete: status task is ERROR ");
                    displayMessage("DATA INSERT ERROR", true);
                }
                onBackPressed(); //This will exit the screen, you should consider whether to use it
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

//========================================= below code is for activity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    void displayMessage(String message, boolean isLengthLong) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int longShow = isLengthLong ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, longShow).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Demo extends BaseActivity {
    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        displayMessage("Ahihi", false);
    }

    public void yourMethod() {
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // Put the log here, Check the log outputted from mobile on android studio to make sure this is working
                Log.d(TAG, "yourMethod: onComplete: status task is " + task.isSuccessful());
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    displayMessage("DATA INSERTED", true);
                } else {
                    // Put the log here, Check the log outputted from mobile on android studio to make sure this is working
                    Log.d(TAG, "yourMethod: onComplete: status task is ERROR ");
                    displayMessage("DATA INSERT ERROR", true);
                }
                onBackPressed(); //This will exit the screen, you should consider whether to use it
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and still no error toast sir

Comment: Can you send error for me

Comment: No error sir its just no toast message if the qr code is wrong

Comment: I updated my post, your check it, please

Comment: thankyou wait ill try it

Comment: i think it conflict my whole code. it has error i cant post my whole code here maybe i can send it to you and look what suppose to be the problem?

Comment: i post an answer of my whole code sir

Comment: you should put Log.d into to track error:
Then follow for bug investigation
Log.d(TAG, "yourMethod: onComplete: status task is " + task.isSuccessful());

 Log.d(TAG, "yourMethod: onComplete: status task is ERROR ");